# Using wysiwyg editor in the admin text area

Tags: django, django-admin, wysiwyg, redactor

I have bought a licence for the [Redactor wysiwyg](https://imperavi.com/redactor/), and now I want to use it in my admin text area. I have got the javscript and css files to include. But I am not sure how to integrate the Redactor wysiwyg into the django admin text area. I have seen some other plugins also, but they are outdated versions, and I want to use the latest version. How can I use it in my admin? Your guidance will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Look into existing integration solutions https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Yes. I tried using that, but its an old version. I will look into that.

Comment: The github link is broken now, but the package still exists on pypi.  There seems to be a recent fork here https://github.com/javipalanca/django-wysiwyg-redactor